# Is there a lossless solution to pack binary data into JavaScript string literals, for code-golf reasons?

Tags: javascript, string, binary, compression

I want to pack some binary data into JS string literals. If I just use base64 encodings, I'll be wasting 10/16 of the total space used, as this will only fit 6 bits per character, when javascript actually uses 16 bits per character. Is there a way to pack data into JS literals without such loss?

Comment: [`LZ77`](https://npmjs.org/package/lz77) perhaps?

Comment: *cough* Unicode *cough*

Comment: Your JS source files don't have to use a 16 bit character encoding. Why not use UTF-8? Then we'd be storing 3 bytes of binary data for every 4 characters in the source file (4 bytes).